# How to get a name id from multiple array in one common variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array, local-storage

This is my local storage array and i want "name" id from all they array .. how can i get it using angular js or js ?

```
[{"email":"John@a.com","pass":"Doe","name":"John" },
{"email":"Anna@a.com","pass":"Smith","name":"Smith"},
{"email":"Peter@a.com","pass":"Jones","name":"Jones"}]
```

```js
 var app = angular.module('app',['ngStorage']);
        app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){

            $scope.complete=function(){
                debugger
                localStorage["data"] = localStorage.getItem('person');
                $scope.obj = JSON.parse(localStorage["data"]);
                console.log($scope.obj['0'].name);
                $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                    source:  $scope.obj['0'].name
                });
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really anything specific for Angular. You just need [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var data = [{"email":"John@a.com","pass":"Doe","name":"John" },
{"email":"Anna@a.com","pass":"Smith","name":"Smith"},
{"email":"Peter@a.com","pass":"Jones","name":"Jones"}];

var names = data.map(function(user) {
    return user.name;
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(names, null, 4))
```

However, here is piece of Angular advice: don't use `$( "#tags" ).autocomplete` in controller, create dedicated directive for this DOM stuff, controller is not the place for this.